# Code::Blocks и пути к DLL для отладки

Tags: c, dll, path

Подскажите, существует ли в **Code::Blocks** способ задать пути, по которым в режиме отладки будут искаться используемые **DLL**?

У меня есть проект, в котором используется множество библиотек, которые используют **DLL**.

Папка с проектом содержит в себе следующие папки:

1. Source
2. Graphic
3. Sound
4. Libs

В папке **Libs** находятся папки с используемыми библиотеками, их много. Проблема в том, что я не могу из **IDE** запустить проект ни в режиме **Debug**, ни в режиме **Release**, потому что сразу получаю сообщение о том, что используемые **DLL** не найдены.

Это и понятно, библиотеки ищутся в каталоге запуска, а так же еще *кое-где*, но меня такое поведение не устраивает.

Я хочу, чтобы при запуске приложения из **IDE** (например, во время отладки) все используемые **DLL** искались в папке **Libs**, а уже при распространении пользовательской версии программы я просто буду класть все **DLL** в общий каталог с **exe**.

Comment: [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order)

Comment: Если gcc собираете, то добавить ключ `-L/путь к библиотекам/` в дополнительных опциях компилятора.

Comment: @NewView Это команда для линкера, при запуске указанные пути не учитываются.

Comment: Если библиотеки динамические, и при запуске жалуется на их отсутствие, тогда можно добавить ещё и `-Wl,-rpath=/путь к библиотекам/`.